# Does phonegap app works on xcode 4.0?

Tags: xcode, macos, cordova

I have mac os X 10.6.3, I want to create phonegap application to work on it, so which version of xcode I need to download? I have already mac os x 10.5.8 and xcode 3.1.4, but i can not buid phonegap app into it. And how to install xCode in snow leopard 10.6.3?

Answer (score 0):

For Snow Leopard 10.6, you can download the version 1.5.0 of Cordova / Phonegap.

Check this link for more information about how to get started with Cordova / Phonegap, version 1.5.0: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.5.0/guide_getting-started_ios_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20iOS

However, I think you'll need XCode 4.